# Is it is mandatory to store both entities data when storing in core data?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am creating a Core Data application where:

`category` entity has the following attributes

> **catid**:int
>
> **catname**:string
>
> **randomrelation**:to-many rel to brandom entity

`brandom` is another entity having attributes

> **cid**:category entity
>
> **no**:int
>
> **arr**:int

My code is the following

```
category *c=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"category" inManagedObjectContext:context];

for (int i=0; i<[arrayofnumbers count]; i++) {
                
    brandom *r=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"brandom" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    c.catid=[NSNumber numberWithInt:i];
    r.cid=c;
    r.no=[NSNumber numberWithInt:i+1];
    int objectatindex=[[arrayofnumbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    NSLog(@"object at index:%i",objectatindex);
    r.arr=[NSNumber numberWithInt:objectatindex];
    [set addObject:r];
}

c.randomrelation=r;
NSLog(@"set element count=%i",[set count]);
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question. What is it that you are asking? Can you explain?

Comment: I am having two entity 


first one category


second one qrandom



,relation between category to qrandom is many to many

,and from qrandom to category is one to many

,i am asking that

,how to store the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not pretty sure if I understood your question.

About your title question, if you are asking if it is mandatory to store data for different etities that are linked with a relatiosnhip, the answer is it **depends**.

You could do that in different times within your application lifecycle if the properties (the relationship) has been declared as optional (1) or you must set them at the same time if you declared is as non-optional (2).

So, if in the first case (1) if could set you create the `category` entity and set its relationship `randomrelation` in a different time. In the second one (2), you need to set both in the same time, since Core Data will give a consistency error.

**Some notes about your model.**

First call the enities like class name, e.g. `Category` instead of `category`, and adopt the camel case notation.

Second, create an inverse relationships from `Brandom` to `Category`. Inverse rels allow you to maintain the graph consistency. In your model `Category` has a to-many rel to `Brandom` declared as **Optional** and `Brandom` has an inverse and **non-Optional** rel (one-to-one) to `Category`. This allows you to create a `Category` with zero or more `Brandom` **but** a `Brandom` cannot "live" without a `Category`.

Hope that helps.